# Syntax rewriting

Tags: c#, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, roslyn

I need to transform all of the properties of a certain class using Roslyn.

**What is the recommended way to apply more than one transformation to a syntax tree without invalidating references into it?**

---

Here is what I've tried and where I'm stuck:

- In the first pass a descendant of `CSharpSyntaxWalker` is visiting all `PropertyDeclarationSyntax` nodes, and storing them in a list.
- In the second pass a `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` is transforming the nodes while checking that each visited node equals one in the list before transforming it.

The problem with my attempt is: When I transform a property I add new fields to the class which causes the class to mutate. All the references in the list to the other properties become invalid in the new tree for the class.

It seems to be inefficient to revisit the whole class, and either way I cannot detect the property nodes already handled due to the reference difference.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what it is that you're doing? Perhaps show some code?

Comment: I've added more info to the original post

Comment: I think you need to just post the relevant code; it's not entirely clear to me what you're doing.

Comment: @DanPuzey I've edited the question, please let me know if what OP is asking is clearer now in your opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**I would not recommend** to reference nodes from a `SyntaxTree` you want to modify. In your case just using a `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` in a single pass (*without* keeping references from a pre-processing pass) would be sufficient, because its `VisitPropertyDeclaration` method will only be called once per property, so there is no need to keep track of the nodes you've already modified.

The `CSharpSyntaxRewriter` also visits the nodes bottom-up, so the overrides should always be called with a node from the original tree. Most likely you have modified the `node` through the call to `base.VisitPropertyDeclaration()` before comparing its reference to the stored one. So you could still keep and compare references if you really wanted to.

```
public class PropertyRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
    public override SyntaxNode VisitPropertyDeclaration(PropertyDeclarationSyntax node)
    {
        // 'node' should be still from the original syntax tree here

        node = (PropertyDeclarationSyntax)base.VisitPropertyDeclaration(node);

        // 'node' might be replaced here

        return node;
    }
}
```

**Instead of keeping references** to the nodes you want to modify, you could annotate them. Annotations to a node will survive modifications of the containing `SyntraxTree` as long as the node itself isn't replaced. You can add them like this:

```
node = node.WithAdditionalAnnotations(
        new SyntaxAnnotation("propertyToChange", "todo"));
```

To retrieve the annotation again either use `node.GetAnnotations("propertyToChange")` or use `GetAnnotatedNodesOrTokens("propertyToChange")` to retrieve all nodes or tokens with an annotation of the given kind ("propertyToChange").